# How to graphically edit the graph of a mathematical function (with python)?

Tags: python, user-interface, math, numpy

Is there already a python package allowing to graphically edit the graph of a function?

Comment: Could you elaborate? Edit in what way? Matplotlib can surely do this.

Comment: I was deliberately unspecific. I suppose any kind of editing of the graph by any possible means. For example in the same way as you can edit a path in google maps. I would be grateful if you can point me to a specific example, or part of the docs, which explains how matplotlib can do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Chaco](http://code.enthought.com/chaco/) is designed to be very interactive, and is significantly more so than matplotlib.  For example, the user can use the mouse to drag the legend to different places on a plot, or lasso data, or move a point around on one plot and change the results in another, or change the color of a plot by clicking on a swatch, etc.

Comment: This is interesting, I will investigate further.

Comment: Great! I think I found it in the `edit_line` example of Chaco:  http://code.enthought.com/projects/chaco/docs/html/annotated_examples.html#edit-line-py

Comment: tom10, thank you for sharing this. The Chaco FAQ offers a comparison with Matplotlib: http://code.enthought.com/projects/chaco/docs/html/user_manual/faq.html. This company, Enthought, is also the primary sponsor of Scipy.

Comment: This looks more like plot/figure editing, whereas I would rather interpret 'function/graph editing' as spline editing. Does Chaco support higher orders of interpolation or just line graphs?

Comment: @Maleev - Yours is an interesting question, but to me it seems different than the OP's.  You might want to ask it as a separate question if you're looking for a package that will do this.  (Most scientific graphing packages that I know of plot straight lines between the data points rather than more elaborate interpolations.)